# Detect GPS in Polygon in Android Google Map API version 2

Tags: android, polygon, google-maps-android-api-2, convex-polygon

I am a new Android developer. I am developing an application about map using Google Map. I created a Polygon on the map and I want to detect through GPS when the position is within Polygon but I do not know how to detect it.

Could you please provide any example or solution? Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: You may want to use a point inside polygon algorithm. Take a look at answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test

Comment: hello you want to use polygon line between current location in other...?